# Disable RSS feed

Tags: feeds

Is it possible to disable the RSS feed? I have a site that it isn't relevant for and just don't want it.

If it is not possible, how can I restrict what appears? How does Drupal choose what content appears in the feed?

Comment: is this for Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Comment: Actually I need to know for both, but either would be good to know.

Comment: I turned mine off in D7, but I can't remember where. Perhaps you need to empty the Feed Description box in here `/admin/config/services/rss-publishing`.

Answer (score 7):

#### Drupal 7

For D7 simply use [Disable RSS](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_rss).

> This module will disable the core RSS feed at
>   http://example.com/rss.xml, and remove any reference to it in the html
>   header.

---

#### Drupal 8

In D8 the feed is provided by a view. Disabling it will disable the feed. Go to http://example.com/admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/feed_1 and disable this display:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the feeds' view on default taxonomy term view.

Answer (score 1):

You disable in views
{example.com}/admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/feed_1
{example.com}/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit/feed_1
[image]

Choices menu Disable Feed

Comment: So the feed is *generated* in Views? And this stops the feed being generated?

Comment: feed had create in views, if you don't want it to show you can disable

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 7**

Just unset the menu entries related to RSS. This allows to disable not only the main rss.xml but also blog and taxonomy feeds.

In a module add a hook to alter the menu:

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['rss.xml']);
  unset($items['blog/%user/feed']);
  unset($items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed']);
}
```

Remember to clear the caches after adding this code (e.g. `drush cc all`).

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit your `page.tpl.php` file and comment out or delete:

```
<?php print $feed_icons; ?>
```

*Note:* This will work only if no one has subscribed to the feed yet.

Answer (score -2):

In Drupal 8 the printing of feeds is called from the theme.
The core base theme "Stable" inserts a line at the bottom of the template core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-view.html.twig that looks like {{ feed_icons }}.  Just delete it.
I'm trying out the basetheme "fortytwo" which has its own template views-view.html.twig and the relevant section is also at the bottom but looks like

```
{% if feed_icons %}
   <div class="feed-icons">
    {{ feed_icons }}
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

so the section to delete may vary.

Comment: I suspect this will delete only the icons for the feeds, and the feed itself will still be available by typing the url

Comment: I want to stop the feed being generated, not just remove the icons.